# Youtube-DL AUDIO-ONLY Playlist

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl

I want to download an AUDIO-ONLY playlist using youtube-dl. I've got the basics down. My version of youtube-dl is up to date, and the command I'm using is:

```
youtube-dl -x --extract-audio --yes-playlist --playlist-start 1 --playlist-end 18 \
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NRHoSXxTpgI&index=1&list=OLAK5uy_lowZyOuAZVs41vEtzV6e0KU8Iue1YQlzg
```

But it keeps getting stuck on

> Deleting original file [filename] (pass -k to keep)

Github doesn't seem to be of any help: https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/12570

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The ampersand (`&`) is a special character in most shells, advising the shell to run the command so far in the background. This should be plainly visible in the first lines after the command execution, which will likely say something like

```
[1] 17156
[2] 17157
```

These is your shell telling you the process ID of the new background processes.

You must escape ampersands with a backslash or quotes, like this:

```
youtube-dl -x --yes-playlist --playlist-start 1 --playlist-end 18 \
'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NRHoSXxTpgI&index=1&list=OLAK5uy_lowZyOuAZVs41vEtzV6e0KU8Iue1YQlzg'
```

`--extract-audio` is the same as `-x`, and thus can be deleted.

For more information, see [the youtube-dl FAQ](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#video-url-contains-an-ampersand-and-im-getting-some-strange-output-1-2839-or-v-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command).

Answer (score 1):

```
-x = extract audio only
-i = ignore errors (skip unavailable files)
```

use only the 'list=...' part, delete the other parameters from copied URL
default is first to last

```
youtube-dl -ix https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=...
```

for individual tracks add e.g. `--playlist-items 4,7-9`

see also: [github/ytdl-org: output template examples](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#output-template-examples)